# display data from database based on other column table laravel 5

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I want to display data from spesific column **users** table, let say **uiprv** column.
and **uiprv** same as **id** from **provinsi** table.

This is User table image:

[image]

and this is provinsi table:

[image]

and now, I've succesfully display data from database but just show "31". 31 is uiprv column from users table, it same thing with id from provinsi table. 
the question is, how to display data not just **31** , but it can be **DKI JAKARTA** . like in **nama_provinsi** at **provinsi** table .

How should I write code in my controller for this.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I only use value="{{$uiprv}}" to display data from database in view

Answer (score 1):

Add this in your App/User.php

```
/**
 * Returns the province of the user
 *
 * @return 
 */
public function province()
{
    // Province is your model related to Provinsi table
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Province');
}
```

From what you've written,

Relationship between User to Province is Many to one.

Reference - https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships

Comment: after add that code in user.php ,  How should I write code in my controller to display data from 31 become DKI Jakarta ?

Answer (score 0):

In your User Model add this

```
    public function province()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Model', 'foreign_key', 'local_key');
    }
```

And in your controller do this

```
$data = User::with('province')->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write a join query to fetch the specific column from table.

e.g.

```
$data = DB::table('users')
->join('provinsi','provinsi.id','=','users.uiprv')
->select('users.name_of_column','provinsi.name_of_column')
->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your user model,

```
     /**
     * Returns the province for the user
     *
     * @return user all details
     */
     public function province()
     {
         return $this->belongsTo('App\Province', 'uiprv', 'id');
     }
```

or

```
     /**
     * Returns the province for the user
     *
     * @return user select details
     */
     public function province()
     {
         return $this->belongsTo('App\Province', 'uiprv', 'id')->select('id', 'nama_provinsi');
     }
```

you can add some other fields also in the select.

Try these and reply for this answer.